# Adding PhoneGap barcode-scanner to Wordpress / Apppresser

Tags: android, wordpress, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I built an Android/IOS app based on Wordpress using Apppresser. Based on this doc http://docs.apppresser.com/article/163-adding-phonegap-plugins I try to add this phonegap plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner into my app.

I added

```
 <gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm">
 <param name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To scan barcodes." />
 </gap:plugin>
```

and

```
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
```

to my config.xml and built the app. The apk finally includes the barcodescanner.js so all looks good. Following the above Apppresser doc I created a demo.js file with

```
var wp = document.getElementById('myApp').contentWindow;
wp.document.getElementById("scan-barcode").addEventListener("click", function(){
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
 function (result) {
     alert("We got a barcode\n" +
           "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
           "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
           "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
 }, 
 function (error) {
     alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
 }
```

);
});

and added it to my Wordpress installation (I did that prior to building the app using the online Apppresser building tool and prior to building the apk-file). Finally I created a Wordpress page and added

```
<input type="button" value="click" name="click" id="click"/>
```

I suppose a click should open the camera on my device but nothing happens...

Anyone out there where I may have gotten lost on the way?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.